# Jump back to previously edited line/word within word document

Tags: user-interface, ms-word, usability

While editing / reviewing a large word document (doc/docx) document, I was searching for a way to jump back to the previously edited text or line but couldn't find any button enabling me to do so.

Has anybody a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the predefined commands "Next Edit" and "Previous Edit". You can for example add these commands in one of the tabs of the ribbon.

For this, right-click the ribbon and select "Customize the Ribbon..."
Select to chhose the command from "All Commands" and use the right-hand side to define where the buttons for the commands shall be placed:

[image]